# D3.js network graph using force-directed layout and rectangles for nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, data-visualization, force-layout

I'm trying to modify Mike's [Force-Directed Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) example to use rectangles instead of circles as nodes.  Also, I want text inside the rectangle.

I have rectangles showing up with text correctly, however they're not attached to the links, and they do not move.

Here's a codepen link:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpgWaz

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 35)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.group);
    })
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px");

node.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .style("font-size", "12px")
    .attr("dy", "1em");

node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });

force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

    node.attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return d.y;
        });
});
```

---

**Update**

Thanks to [Lars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff)'s comment, and his [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXNVNY) it works now.

Updates I made to my code:

1. Add transform illustrated by Lars
2. Changed links to connect at the center of rectangles
3. Added rounded corners to rectangles
4. Gave the text a slight margin indentation
5. Changed to use window width/height

Here my new codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdgREd

```
var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight,
    nodeWidth = 100,
    nodeHeight = 35;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-1500)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .friction(0.5)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("width", nodeWidth)
    .attr("height", nodeHeight)
    .attr("rx", 5)
    .attr("ry", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.group);
    })
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px");

node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 5)
    .attr("y", 2)
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .style("font-size", "12px")
    .attr("dy", "1em");

node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });

force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x + (nodeWidth / 2);
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y + (nodeHeight / 2);
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x + (nodeWidth / 2);
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y + (nodeHeight / 2);
        });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
});
```

Comment: You need to set the `transform` attribute like you're doing when appending the rectangles: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXNVNY

Comment: That did it.  If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `x` and `y` attributes on the `g` elements to change their positions -- this won't do anything. You need to set the `transform` attribute instead, like you're doing when adding the `g` elements. So your `tick` handler function would contain

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});
```

instead of

```
node.attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y;
    });
```

Complete demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXNVNY).